# Android: setting signal strength

Tags: android

I was wondering if you can set signal strength parameters. In andriod.telephony class I only see methods which get you the values, however, is it possible to set values too ?

Comment: Before asking question please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

No.  Signal strength is a measurement of a physical thing-  the ratio of signal to noise of the cellular signal.  You can't set that-  it is whatever it is.  You can set its variable to 1 billion, it won't effect the physical reality.  The only use of it would be to lie to other apps about what the real signal strength is.  And no, there is no way to do that.